# Counting function, comparing lists

Tags: list-manipulation

## Update

I would now like to produce a plot that explores the difference between the squarefree count and the expected mean (without using SquareFreeQ) - something along the lines of:

```
a = PrimeOmega[Range[1000]];
b = PrimeNu[Range[1000]];
ListLinePlot[{#/Zeta[2] - Accumulate[Flatten[Inner[If[#1 === #2, 1, 0] 
&, a, b, List]]]}, Filling -> Axis]
```

or

```
a = PrimeOmega[Range[100]];
b = PrimeNu[Range[100]];
Plot[{x/Zeta[2] - Accumulate[Flatten[Inner[If[#1 === #2, 1, 0] &, a, b, List]]]}, 
{x, 0, 100}, Filling -> Axis]
```

In the hope of achieving something similar to:

```
Plot[{{x/Log[x]} - PrimePi[x]}, {x, 0, 100}, Filling -> Axis]
```

Or alternatively, slightly alter Artes' cf plot (see below).

Instead of:

```
cf = {#, Count[Range[#, # + 500], _?SquareFreeQ]} & /@ Range[0, 100000, 500]
```

Using something like:

```
a = PrimeOmega[Range[100000]];
b = PrimeNu[Range[100000]];
cf = {#, Count[Range[#, # + 500], _?Accumulate[Flatten[Inner[If[#1 === #2, 1, 0] 
&, a, b, List]]]]} & /@ Range[0, 100000, 500]
```

... Much clumsier, I realise, but I would like to avoid using SquareFreeQ if I can.

## Old

I would like mathematica to output instances where `PrimeOmega[x]=PrimeNu[x]` up to a given range. (Clearly in this example, the output will be the set of square free numbers.)

```
a = PrimeOmega[Range[1000000]];
b = PrimeNu[Range[1000000]];
Count[Transpose[{a, b}], {1, 1}]
a = PrimeOmega[Range[1000000]];
b = PrimeNu[Range[1000000]];
Count[Transpose[{a, b}], {2, 2}] .....
```

works, but is (a) very slow, and (b) very clumsy.

I was wondering if there was a more succinct way of putting it?

In addition, I would like to ultimately create a plot for what will essentially be a counting function for `PrimeOmega[x]&&PrimeNu[x]=={1, 1},{2, 2}...` etc. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using both `PrimeOmega` and `PrimeNu` I'd rather use only `SquareFreeQ`.

Let's compare appropriate timings:

```
First @ AbsoluteTiming[ a = PrimeOmega[Range[300000]];
                b = PrimeNu[Range[300000]]; 
                Inner[If[#1 === #2, True, False] &, a, b, List];] 

First @ AbsoluteTiming[SquareFreeQ /@ Range[300000];]
```

> ```
> 19.748000
>  1.521000
> ```

and of course:

```
Inner[ If[ #1 === #2, True, False] &, a, b, List] == (SquareFreeQ /@ Range[300000])
```

> ```
> True
> ```

**Edit**

If we are to find numbers which satisfy `PrimeOmega[x] == PrimeNu[x]]` in a given range
we can use `Select`, e.g.

```
Select[ Range[10^6, 10^6 + 11], SquareFreeQ]
```

> ```
> {1000001, 1000002, 1000003, 1000005, 1000006, 1000007, 1000009, 
>  1000010, 1000011, 1000013, 1000014, 1000015, 1000018, 1000019}
> ```

to count them we use:

```
Count[ Range[10^6, 10^6 + 20], _?SquareFreeQ]
```

> ```
> 14
> ```

of course we might use `Count[Range[10^6, 10^6 + 20], _?(PrimeOmega[#] == PrimeNu[#] &)]` instead but the latter is slower.
Let's define appropriate counting function:

```
cf = {#, Count[Range[#, # + 500], _?SquareFreeQ]} & /@ Range[0, 100000, 500];
```

Namely we count square free numbers in every range: `{0, 500}, {500, 1000},...,{99500, 100000}`.

Let's plot the counting function `cf`:

```
With[{ mcf = Mean @ cf[[All, 2]]}, 
     ListPlot[ cf, AxesOrigin -> {0, 280}, PlotRange -> {280, 320}, AspectRatio -> 1/5, 
               PlotMarkers -> Automatic, Filling -> mcf, 
               Epilog -> {Darker @ Green, Line[{{0, mcf}, {100000, mcf}}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: That's great, but I want to extend it to non squarefree also.

Comment: To ensure that mapping `SquareFreeQ` is better, try to find timings of generating lists `a` and `b`. It takes: `AbsoluteTiming[a = PrimeOmega[Range[300000]]; 
b = PrimeNu[Range[300000]];] `  yields `19.615000` while `AbsoluteTiming[Inner[...]]` only `0.503000`.

Comment: @martin What do you mean by non-squarefree??? I've just provided what you've been looking for. The main problem is generating lists of `PrimeOmega` and `PrimeNu`, instead you can just play with `SquareFreeQ`. Did you miss anything?

Comment: @martin Could you explain what you mean by extension to non-squarefree numbers, and clarify what kind of plot you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry, yes - was looking for this kind of thing:
    a = PrimeOmega[Range[1000]];b = PrimeNu[Range[1000]];
ListPlot[{Accumulate[
   Flatten[Inner[If[#1 === #2, 1, 0] &, a, b, List]]], 
  Accumulate[Flatten[Inner[If[#1 === #2 + 1, 1, 0] &, a, b, List]]], 
  Accumulate[Flatten[Inner[If[#1 === #2 + 2, 1, 0] &, a, b, List]]]}]

Comment: I see what you have done though now ... very interesting! Many thanks for your interpretation! - The plot is most illuminating.

Comment: Quick question - how do I substitute mcf for 500/Zeta[2]?

Comment: @martin It depends on the context where it is going to be used. E.g. `With[{mcf=1000000/Zeta[2]}, ... ]` or `expr/. mcfmcf->1000000/Zeta[2]` or other ways like e.g. `expr/. mcfmcf:>1000000/Zeta[2]`. Look at e.g. answers to this [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33763/hornerform-of-polynomials-in-terms-of-ei-x) to get an idea of differences between `->` and `:>`.

Comment: Sorry - should be 500/Zeta[2] (what mean should be roughly anyway) - just wanted to replace mean line with 500/Zeta[2] & fill to that.

Comment: @ArtesGot it - yes - mcf = 500/Zeta[2]. - Great, thanks.

Comment: Just wondered if there was a way to express cf without using SquareFreeQ (see question update)?

Comment: Many thanks - much appreciated.

Comment: @martin I'll update my answer this evening, I couldn't find time to do it yesterday. I think it's interesting but you should ask questions more clearly at the begining because it may save other's time.

Comment: Yes, I'll try to be more succinct and to the point with my line of questioning - still getting to grips with the whole thing! All of your time spent in answering is really much appreciated though - I have learnt a great deal on this forum just in the past couple of days - really, a great forum. Again, many thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want:

```
Reap[Sow[#, PrimeOmega[#] == PrimeNu[#]] & /@ Range[300000];, True][[2,1]] // Length
```

OR using just `SquareFreeQ` which is obviously faster

```
Reap[Sow[#, SquareFreeQ[#]] & /@ Range[300000];, True][[2, 1]] // Length
```

Here is another way based on `Inner`

```
a = PrimeOmega @ Range[300000]; b = PrimeNu @ Range[300000];
Inner[If[#1 === #2, True, ## &[]] &, a, b, List] // Length
```

Comment: Outputs list, rather than counting number of times PrimeOmega[n] is equal to PrimeNu[n] within a given range. Output should be single number. - Sorry, obviously I am not being very clear!

Comment: @martin. See my edit.

Comment: Yes! Perfect! Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In general, to count how many entries in your two lists are the same, you can use

```
a = PrimeOmega[Range[1000000]];
b = PrimeNu[Range[1000000]];

Length@a - (Unitize[a - b] // Total)
```

> 607926

The last line, the counting line, will be fast.

However for the underlying problem, I will rephrase what @Artes has pointed out already:  `PrimeOmega[x] == PrimeNu[x]` if and only if `x` is square-free.  So `SquareFree` will be a faster way to solve the whole problem, as Artes has shown.

---

**Response to updated question**

Perhaps this is what you're after:

```
a = PrimeOmega[Range[100000]];
b = PrimeNu[Range[100000]];
sums = Accumulate[1 - Unitize[a - b]];

Plot[x/Zeta[2] - sums[[Min[1 + Floor[x], Length@sums]]], {x, 0, 100000},
 Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: OK, yes, got that thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Update

OK - First part of update solved:

```
a = PrimeOmega[Range[100000]];
b = PrimeNu[Range[100000]];
c = Range[100000];
ListLinePlot[{c/Zeta[2] - Accumulate[Flatten[Inner[If[#1 === #2, 1, 0] 
&, a, b, List]]]}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

... Just unsure how to modify Artes' count plot.

## Old

Sorry Artes, yes - was looking for this kind of thing:

```
a = PrimeOmega[Range[100]];
b = PrimeNu[Range[100]];
ListPlot[{Accumulate[Flatten[Inner[If[#1 === #2, 1, 0] &, a, b, List]]],    
Accumulate[Flatten[Inner[If[#1 === #2 + 1, 1, 0] &, a, b, List]]],
Accumulate[Flatten[Inner[If[#1 === #2 + 2, 1, 0] &, a, b, List]]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: You can edit your questions or answers to improve them. But I think you've included this plot in another answer, i.e. [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33743/plot-counting-function-semi-primes/33755#33755), posting duplicate answers or questions is not (in general) appropriate.

Comment: Nearly the same - only slightly different:

Comment: 1st plot is square free, second has one square + a few other things, third, ...& so on

Comment: I meant you posted another question where it was more clearly stated what were your expectations. From the above question it is not clear what is the essence.

Comment: Other thread was asking about plot comparing semiprime & prime counting functions; this one was about squarefree, numbers with square prime factors, numbers with cubed prime factors ,etc. counting functions

Comment: Both similar though, I admit!

Answer (score 1):

Late, but a slightly different approach avoiding`SquareFreeQ`, `PrimeOmega`,
and `PrimeNu`. See Sloane's [A143658](https://oeis.org/A143658), the number
of squarefree integers not exceeding $2^n$. Fast, since the sum is only
to the square root of the upper limit; however, it only has samples at the
powers of 2.

```
SloanesA143658[n_] := 
   Module[{t = 2^n}, 
          ParallelSum[MoebiusMu[k] Floor[t/k^2], {k, 1, Floor[Sqrt[t]]}]]
```

Plot the count as dots with the theoretical line, $2^n/\zeta(2)$, in red.

```
With[{nmax = 20}, 
   ListLogPlot[Table[{n, SloanesA143658[n]}, {n, 1, nmax}], 
               Frame -> True, 
               FrameLabel -> {"Exponent  n", "Number of SquareFree"}, 
               PlotLabel -> "SquareFree Numbers <= 2^n", BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, 
               Epilog -> {Red, Line[Table[{n, Log[2^n/Zeta[2]]}, {n, 1, nmax}]]}
   ]]
```

Plot the relative error of the theoretical value versus the count.

```
With[{nmax = 20}, 
   ListLogPlot[Table[{n, Abs[2^n/Zeta[2] - SloanesA143658[n]]/2^n}, {n, 1, nmax}], 
               Frame -> True, Joined -> True, 
               FrameLabel -> {"Exponent  n", "Relative Error"}, 
               PlotLabel -> "SquareFree Numbers <= 2^n", BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}
   ]]
```