# Plot counting function semi primes

Tags: plotting

I am trying to generate a plottable semi-prime counting function.

Have tried:

```
DiscretePlot[Gather[{a = PrimeOmega[Range[100]];
b = PrimeNu[Range[100]];
Count[Transpose[{a, b}], {2, 2}]}
+
{a = PrimeOmega[Range[100]];
b = PrimeNu[Range[100]];
Count[Transpose[{a, b}], {2, 1}]}],{x, 0, 15}, Filling -> Bottom]]
```

but really have no clue as to where to go from here!

Comment: Perhaps you should be a little bit more specific about what you want to achieve.

Comment: For example, Gather[PrimeOmega[Range[100]]]gives a kind of counting function for PrimeOmega[#]. I still don't know how to plot this though.

Comment: Gather[PrimeOmega[Range[10]]] 

outputs the following:

{{0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2}, {3}}

How can I plot this as one continuous plot - 

ie - in the form of:

Plot[PrimePi[x], {x, 0, 10}, Filling -> Bottom]

Comment: Having done that, how would I then create a semi-prime counting plot?

Comment: Given that:a = PrimeOmega[Range[100]];
b = PrimeNu[Range[100]];
Count[Transpose[{a, b}], {2, 2}]} PLUS
a = PrimeOmega[Range[100]];
b = PrimeNu[Range[100]];
Count[Transpose[{a, b}], {2, 1}]} gives all semi primes up to a given range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = PrimeOmega[Range[100]];
b = PrimeNu[Range[100]];
ListPlot[{Accumulate[Flatten[Inner[If[#1 === #2 === 2, 1, 0] &, a, b, List]] + 
Inner[If[#1 === #2 + 1 === 2, 1, 0] &, a, b, List]],
Table[PrimePi[x], {x, 100}]}]
```

[image]

Makes quite a nice comparison

Comment: Thanks, Artes. Just a quick question - how do you link these images?

Comment: When editing an answer there are links to adequate tools, e.g. `Ctrl + G` opens a window to upload an image, e.g. in `gif` format.

Comment: If you think you've got the best or the most appropriate answer to a question you may accept it by clicking a tick mark under the vote counter of a given answer. Usually it is sufficient to wait one or two days to get an expected answer.

Comment: Great - OK, thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
dat = Thread[{PrimeOmega[Range[100]], 
    PrimeNu[Range[100]]}] /. {{2, 1} | {2, 2} -> 1, {_, _} -> 0}

ListPlot[Accumulate@dat,Filling->Axis]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This formula for the number of semi-primes less than or equal to $n$ is from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Semiprime.html. A semi-prime may be written as $p*q$, where we can assume $p\le q$. The number of semi-primes less than or equal to a maximum $n$ requires checking $\pi(\sqrt{n})$ values of $p$, where $\pi$ is the prime counting function. For each possible $p_k$ there are $\pi(n/p_k)$ values of $q$ such that $p*q\le n$. However, the condition $p\le q$ means that not all these possible $q$ are allowed. The first $k-1$ possible values of $q$ must be dropped. Thus,
$\pi^{(2)}(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{\pi(\sqrt{n})} \left[ \pi(n/p_k)-k+1 \right]$

```
SemiprimeCount[n_Integer] := Sum[PrimePi[n/Prime[k]]-k+1, {k,1,PrimePi[Sqrt[n]]}]
SetAttributes[SemiprimeCount,Listable]
```

I make plots using the function`BlockPlot`

```
 BlockPlot[v_] := Partition[Flatten[
    {1, v[[1]], Table[{i, v[[i - 1]], i, v[[i]]}, {i, 2, Length[v]}]}], 2]
```

and, for example,

```
ListLinePlot[BlockPlot[SemiprimeCount[Range[50]]], Frame->True, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize->14}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Number  n", "Semiprime Count"}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Number of Semiprimes \[LessEqual] n", 
   Filling -> Automatic]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = PrimeOmega[Range[100]];
b = PrimeNu[Range[100]];
ListPlot[Accumulate[Flatten[Inner[If[#1 === #2 === 2, 1, 0] &, a, b, List]] 
+ Inner[If[#1 === #2 + 1 === 2, 1, 0] &, a, b, List]],
Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image]