# HornerForm of polynomials in terms of E^(i x)

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I want to know how to get the `HornerForm` of the following expression in terms of `E^(I x)`:

```
 E^(I x) + 2 E^(2 I x) + 3 E^(3 I x) + 4 E^(4 I x) + 5 E^(5 I x) + 
     6 E^(6 I x) + 7 E^(7 I x) + 8 E^(8 I x) + 9 E^(9 I x) + 10 E^(10 I x)
```

`HornerForm[ expr, E^(I x)]` doesn't work as well as something like `Collect[ expr, E^(I x]]`.
How can I get the desired form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most straightforward way appears to be using carefully simple replacement rules involving `RuleDelayed` rather than `Rule`:

```
HornerForm[ E^(I x) + 2 E^(2 I x) + 3 E^(3 I x) + 4 E^(4 I x) + 5 E^(5 I x) 
           + 6 E^(6 I x) + 7 E^(7 I x) + 8 E^(8 I x) + 9 E^(9 I x) + 10 E^(10 I x) /. 
E^(Complex[0, b_] x) :> z^b, z] /. z :> E^(I x)
```

[image]

```
% // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

We should remember one subtlety using **patterns** in **replacement rules** involving **complex** (imaginary) factors, which we can illustrate with e.g.:

```
FullForm @ Unevaluated[ 5 I x]
FullForm[ 5 I x]
```

> ```
>  Unevaluated[ Times[5, I, x]]
>  Times[ Complex[0, 5], x]
> ```

namely: built-in rewriting rules of the system automatically evaluate `Times[ 5, I]` to `Complex[0, 5]` being an atom:

```
AtomQ[ Complex[0, 5]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

therefore we couldn't make our rule simpler and had used `E^(Complex[0, b_] x) :> z^b` instead of something like apparently simpler `E^(I b_ x) :> z^b`.

Comment: Oops apparently we took almost the same approach! :P

Comment: @Artes Great! Rule Replace, I got that

Comment: @Artes Great! But it seems that ` Times[a_, Power[E, Times[Complex[0, b_], x]]] :> a z^b ` is rebundant, right?

Comment: @matheorem yes, that was redundant, just improved.

Comment: @LeoFang You had to map `Power[E, Times[Complex[0, #], x]] -> y^# &` because you had used `Rule` (`->`) instead of `RuleDelayed` (`:>`)

Comment: @Artes yes so I replaced those elements one by one. Using RuleDelayed indeed is a bit more flexible!

Answer (score 2):

This only works for the special case given in your post:

```
input =  E^(I x) + 2 E^(2 I x) + 3 E^(3 I x) + 4 E^(4 I x) + 5 E^(5 I x) + 
 6 E^(6 I x) + 7 E^(7 I x) + 8 E^(8 I x) + 9 E^(9 I x) + 10 E^(10 I x);
HornerForm[input/. (Power[E, Times[Complex[0, #], x]] -> y^# & /@ 
 Range[1, 10])] /. y -> Exp[I x]
```