# How to make this particular replacement involving exp

Tags: replacement

I apologize if similar questions have already been asked, but I have some difficulties with replacements in Mathematica and I would like to make a substitution like

```
Exp[I m phiA] --> f[m,phiA]
Exp[I m phiB] --> f[m,phiB]
```

where m is a number and `phiA`,`phiB` are variables, in expressions that contain sums in the exponent, e.g.

```
2 + Exp[-2 I (phiA + phiB)] + Exp[2 I phiA + 2 I phiB]
```

which should give

```
1/4 + f[-2,phiA] f[-2,phiB] + f[2,phiA] f[2,phiB]
```

Is this possible? How can it be done?

Comment: Lookk at a related question: [HornerForm of polynomials in terms of E^(i x)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33763/hornerform-of-polynomials-in-terms-of-ei-x).

Comment: I managed to replace the form `Exp[m I phi]` using `Complex`. How can I transform `Exp[-2 I (phiA + phiB)]` to a product of elements like `Exp[m I phi]`?

Comment: E.g. `Exp[-2 I (phiA + phiB)] /. 
 Exp[a_ (b_ + c_)] :> HoldForm[Exp[a b] Exp[a c]]`.

Comment: Oh thanks! Can it be generalized to sums with an arbitrary number of addends?

Answer (score 2):

When attempting to deal with replacements a good general rule is to examine the `FullForm` of the components.

**Expression 1**

FullForm[Exp[I m phiA]]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Expression 2**

FullForm[Exp[-2 I (phiA + phiB)]]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Expression 3**

FullForm[Exp[2 I phiA + 2 I phiB]]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note carefully that even though `Exp[-2 I (phiA + phiB)]` is algebraically equivalent to `Exp[-2 I phiA -2 I phiB]` the two FullForms are not the same.

Pattern matching uses the ***syntax*** to find matches.

We can make replacement rules as follows.

Take the `FullForm` of the expression and insert named patterns.

Note: You can stay with the exact `FullForm` syntax but it doesn't print well on Stack Exchange so I will use the expanded `FullForm`.

**Expression 1**

```
Exp[I m phiA] /. E^(I m_ phiA_) -> f[m, phiA]

f[m, phiA]
```

We will come back to Expression 2 in a moment.

**Expression 3**

```
Exp[2 I phiA + 2 I phiB] /. E^(Complex[0, m_] phiA_ + Complex[0, n_] phiB_) -> 
  f[m, phiA] f[n, phiB]

f[2, phiA] f[2, phiB]
```

**Expression 2**

The question was asked in a comment if it would be possible to generalize expression 2 to an arbitrary number of components. This can be done as follows:

```
FullForm[Exp[-2 I (phiA + phiB + phiC)]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Replace the `Plus` with `List` and use `Map`.

```
Exp[-2 I (phiA + phiB + phiC)] /. E^(Complex[0, m_] (first_ + rest__)) :> 
  Times@@Map[f[m, #] &, List[first, rest]]
```

produces

```
f[-2, phiA] f[-2, phiB] f[-2, phiC]
```

**Summary**

All of the rules would be placed in a list to transform expressions containing exponents with arguments that match the forms in expressions one, two and three.

```
expr /. {
  E^(I m_ phiA_) -> f[m, phiA],
  E^(Complex[0, m_] (phiA_ + phiB_)) -> f[m, phiA] f[m, phiB],
  E^(Complex[0, m_] (first_ + rest__)) :> 
   Times @@ Map[f[m, #] &, List[first, rest]]
  }
```